# How can I create this data structure?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I am creating a geometry app. I have created `NSMutableOrderedSets` for both the planes and points present in a diagram. What I am trying to do is create some way to store which points are on which planes. I have thought about an `NSDictionary` but there could be multiple points on a plane or a point on multiple planes so there could no be a unique reference key that I can think of. I have thought of creating an `NSArray` for each plane and then an array of those arrays but there is no way to know how many planes there will be as they are set at runtime. I have also thought about several other things and am completely out of ideas.  Can someone please help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `Plane` Object and insert a `NSArray` in it as a `Point` container. Make a `NSArray` and add every `Plane` to it.

I hope it be useful for you!